# With the new EU roaming, what will I pay for calls within a foreign country?

Tags: europe, cellphones, eu, roaming

EU roaming charges are about to be abolished. What does this mean for calls made from abroad?

Suppose at home my phone provider charges A for a call in my country and B for a call to an EU country.

Now when abroad, will it cost A or B to make a call within the foreign country?
Will it cost A or B to call home (from abroad)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting on June 15th 2017, when roaming withing the EEA (all EU countries, Iceland, Lichtenstein and Norway), you will not be charged more than the price for a domestic call on your home network if you call any fixed or mobile number within the EEA. If you have a subscription plan with included minutes, these minutes will also be valid when roaming. You can not be charged for receiving calls.

So, the answer to your question is A.

One point where the regulation seems unclear is how to charge calls to service lines using so called shared cost services (like area codes 0845 in UK or 0180 in Germany). For example my cell phone subscription includes all calls to regular fixed line or mobile phone numbers, but has a relatively steep charge per minute for calls to shared cost numbers. There are even different charges depending on the type of shared cost service. If I roam in another EEA country and call a shared cost service in that country or another EEA country, it is not obvious from the wording in the regulation if the call should be covered by my included minutes, or if my operator can charge for it and at which rate.

International calls from your home network to other EEA countries are not covered by the regulation and can be charged as your provider likes.

Comment: Ah, so even when I'm home (so not roaming) I'll be able to make a call to any EU country for the same price A? If so, that all makes sense. Otherwise, if I'd still be charged B to make a call from home to a foreign country, it would seem that I pay less from abroad than from home, which is where my confusion came from.

Comment: @akkarin Eh, no. See my last paragraph.

Comment: I see. So someone who lives in the UK may end up having cheaper calls from Spain to France than from the UK to France!

Comment: @akkarin yes... In my case : calling from Spain to Germany will be free but call Germany or Spain from France will cost me money ^^ (since I'm living in France) I'd add something: you speak about UK but as UK won't be in EU at some point, roaming fees in UK might applies...

Comment: @dotixx: I believe the legislation affects the entire EEA. It already includes Norway for instance.

Comment: @akkarin As I also wrote, the regulations are for the entire EEA. Some operators also voluntarily offer the same roaming conditions for non-EEA countries like e.g. Switzerland. When UK leaves the EU, it will unless anything else is negotiated also leave the EEA, so it is to be expected, that the regulation of roaming rates in the UK will cease when UK leaves the EU.

Answer (score 3):

Your home provider will pay the local provider because it is the local provider which provides the network you are using to reach the other phone.

Plus, be careful, EU said that roaming cost will be abolished but it didn't say anything from usage from your home country to another EU country. Most likely this will be at providers' discretion...

EDIT: your carrier should not charge anything if you make a call from EU country if your subscription at your home carrier includes voice calls. Same goes for texts. If they are not included, then you'll be charge the same price as domestic call.

[Source](https://ec.europa.eu/digital-single-market/en/content/frequently-asked-questions-roam-home)

Comment: That doesn't quite answer my question. I know that my provider can still charge B > A for calls from home to a foreign country. But what will they charge me when I visit the country and make a call?

Comment: @akkarin oh, sorry... will update my answer :)

Comment: So the scenario is that I pay different prices A and B depending on the call's *target* country. Will I pay exactly the same rates even when visiting the very same target country, i.e. will I pay the domestic price to call home whilst paying the increased abroad price when making a local call abroad? Sorry to be so precise here but I really want an answer to my two "A or B" questions above. ^^

Comment: @akkarin there won't be any "increased abroad price" anymore starting on June 15th, so you'll pay the same price as if you were calling from France to France (or Germany to Germany or whatever domestic call)

Comment: @akkarin see here : http://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/consumers/telecoms-internet/mobile-roaming-costs/index_en.htm "no extra roaming fee, same as domestic price"

Comment: So the legislation affects not only roaming fees but also means that my provider can't charge extra for calls to EU countries (made from home)?

Comment: @akkarin this is at your home carrier's discretion as far as I understood ... That legislation affects roaming ... not "home usage"